# ITC app vs itunes connect web page, sales and trends

Tags: app-store-connect

Why is it when I check my iTunes Connect app on my phone the daily app downloads vary to the iTunes connect web page, for example the ITC app says I have 6 downloads of a particular app and the iTunes connect webpage says I have 9 on the same date?  Which is more accurate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ITC website has an option in the upper right corner of *Sales and Trends* to show data in UTC or Local time. It defaults to UTC. The app on the other hand apparently shows data in Local time. If you change the site to Local than the numbers match... at least for us.